# wtforms will not return form.validate() as true

Tags: flask, flask-wtforms

I'm trying to validate inputs for a contact form loosely following [Lalith Polepeddi's tutorial](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/intro-to-flask-signing-in-and-out--net-29982?_ga=2.114148545.776213538.1546216723-614787110.1546216723).  I have used this tutorial before with slight adjustments, but this time the inputs will not validate no matter what I try.

if form.validate() in my routes.py always returns false.  I uploaded the (entire venv to github with only the offending code)https://github.com/1988mazdab2000/wtfwtf.git

forms.py file:

```
class ContactForm(Form):
  name = TextField("Name",  [validators.Required("Please enter your name.")])
  email = TextField("Email",  [validators.Required("Please enter your email address."), validators.Email("Please enter your email address.")])
  subject = TextField("Subject",  [validators.Required("Please enter a subject.")])
  message = TextAreaField("Message",  [validators.Required("Please enter a message.")])
submit = SubmitField("Send")
```

my routes.py file:

```
from flask import render_template, request, flash
from forms import ContactForm
from flask_mail import Message, Mail

mail = Mail()

@app.route('/')
def home():
  return render_template('home.html')

@app.route('/about')
def about():
  return render_template('about.html')

@app.route('/contact', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def contact():
  form = ContactForm()

  if request.method == 'POST':
    if form.validate() == False:
      flash('All fields are required.')
      return render_template('contact.html', form=form)
    else:
      msg = Message(form.subject.data, sender='contact@example.com', recipients=['your_email@example.com'])
      msg.body = """
      From: %s <%s>
      %s
      """ % (form.name.data, form.email.data, form.message.data)
      mail.send(msg)

      return render_template('contact.html', success=True)

  elif request.method == 'GET':
return render_template('contact.html', form=form)
```

any help with this would be greatly appreciated.  I have used identical code to do this in the last three months and I'm stuck.

I've tried using different validators and started with a fresh install of raspbian on two different Pis.

I'd like for the form validators to work properly.

Comment: your GitHub link is not working

Comment: Fixed, sorry about that

Comment: did you check validate_on_submit ?

Answer (score 0):

In the template use  `{{ form.hidden_tag() }}`  for csrf protection.

```
<form action="{{ url_for('contact') }}" method="post">

      {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

As @VillageMonkey said, use `validate_on_submit`. More can be found in [official documentation](https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=form#flask_wtf.FlaskForm.validate_on_submit).

Here is an example of using form validation using `Flask-WTF`. In this example, the login form requires a valid email address and a password with at least 6 and at most 35 characters long.

`app.py`:

```
from flask import render_template, url_for, request, redirect, flash, Flask
from forms import LoginForm

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'secret key'

@app.route("/login", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    form = LoginForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.validate_on_submit() == False:
          flash('Form validation failed')          
          return render_template('login.html', form=form)
        user_email = form.email.data
        user_password = form.password.data
        if user_email and user_password:
            return "{} - {}".format(user_email, user_password)
    return render_template('login.html', form=form)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

`forms.py`:

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, PasswordField, SubmitField, BooleanField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired, Length, Email, EqualTo

class LoginForm(FlaskForm):
    email = StringField('Email', validators=[DataRequired(), Email()])
    password = PasswordField('Password', validators=[DataRequired(), Length(min=6, max=35)])
    submit = SubmitField('Login')
```

`login.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Login</title>
</head>
<body>
  {% with messages = get_flashed_messages() %}
  {% if messages %}
  <ul class=flashes>
    {% for message in messages %}
    <li>{{ message }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>
  {% endif %}
  {% endwith %}
  <form method="POST" action="">
    {{ form.csrf_token }}
    <div>
      {{ form.email.label }} {{ form.email }}
      {% if form.email.errors %}
      <ul style="color: red;">
        {% for error in form.email.errors %}
        <li>{{ error }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
      </ul>
      {% endif %}
    </div>
    <div>
      {{ form.password.label }} {{ form.password }}
      {% if form.password.errors %}
      <ul style="color: red;">
        {% for error in form.password.errors %}
        <li>{{ error }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
      </ul>
      {% endif %}
    </div>
    <div>
      {{ form.submit }}
    </div>
  </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Directory structure:

```
.
├── app.py
├── forms.py
└── templates
    └── login.html
```

`requirements.txt`:

```
Click==7.0
Flask==1.0.2
Flask-WTF==0.14.2
itsdangerous==1.1.0
Jinja2==2.10
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
Werkzeug==0.15.0
WTForms==2.2.1
```

**Output:**

Get request of `login` route:

[image: login form]

Post request of `login` route (failed validation):

[image: failed validation]

Post request of `login` route (after successful validation):

[image: validated response]